# How do you create a rectangle table filled with a color with HTML / CSS?

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a table with filled color and I used below code, but I am getting an error. Can someone help me with that? Thank you for your help in advance.

```
<td>
    <div style="background-color: #2E21FF; width:500px;height:100px;border:1px solid #000; padding:0;margin:0;">This is a rectangle!</div>
</td>
```

Comment: What error do you get? Other than only posting part of the code for a complete table, the div code seems fine.

Comment: What error are you getting? The code you provided in your question works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ts913p0v/

Comment: You need to declare <table> and <tr> tags then nest <td> within that <tr>. Your code is incomplete for a table.

Comment: trying to create different coloured rectangle in a table but I'm new in HTML and CSS. I am not able to create different colour rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<td>` is styled differently with a class color-box and all the colors are then separately handled with their classes. Below is an example.

```
.color-box span {
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.color-box {
  border: 1px #aaa solid;
  padding: 6px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 0 #888;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 0 #888;
}
.blue-box {
  background-color: #0088cc;
}
.red-box {
  background-color: #ff6161;
}
.green-box {
  background-color: #70c24a;
}
.yellow-box {
  background-color: #e0e03e;
}




<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="color-box">
      <span class="blue-box"></span> #0088cc
    </td>
    <td class="color-box">
      <span class="yellow-box"></span> #e0e03e
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="color-box">
      <span class="green-box"></span> #70c24a
    </td>
    <td class="color-box">
      <span class="red-box"></span> #ff6161
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to create a table, you can style it much easier and it also makes your HTML markup look cleaner.

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      Data for cell here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

CSS:

```
.table {
  display: table-cell
  background-color: #2E21FF;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell
}
```

---

---

You can add more table cells rows by creating more divs with the classes table-cell and row within the div classed 'table'.